# Using only JavaScript to create a jump animation

Tags: javascript, animation

I don't know why my code doesn't allow me to jump properly.
I can move left and right just fine, but when I try to jump using the up arrow it brings me to a random height and I don't fall back down.

I'm trying to build a platformer and get down the basic code needed.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var keys =[];

var width = 500,
    height = 400,
    speed = 4,
    jumpHeight = 10,
    gravity = 10.0,
    velocity = null;

var player= {
    x:0,
    y:380,
    width:20,
    height:20,
    speed:4,
    velX:0,
    velY:0,
    jumpBoo:false,
};


window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e){
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);

/*
    keys
    up-38
    down-40
    right-39
    left-37
*/
function game(){
    update();
    render();
}
function jump(){
    if(keys[38]){
        if(player.y=250){
            player.y+=speed*5;
        }
        if(player.y<250){
            player.y-=speed*3;
        }
    }
}
function update(){
    jump();
    if(keys[37]) player.x-=speed;
    if(keys[39]) player.x+=speed;

    if(player.x <0) player.x=0;
    if(player.y <0) player.y=0;
    if(player.x >= width - player.width) player.x = width - player.width;
    if(player.y >= height - player.height) player.y = height - player.height;
    if(player.y >= height-player.height){
        player.y = height - player.height;
    }
}
function render(){
    context.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
}
setInterval(function(){
    game();
}, 1000/30);
```

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
#mainCanvas{
    background-color: #bcbcbc;
}
```

Comment: You're using an array to store an unordered series of values which is against the modus operandi of an array - it may be worthwhile switching to an object instead (`keys = {}` instead of `keys=[]`). Also there is clearly some important code that you haven't included here. Where are the player's coordinates updated? Be sure to include every piece of the puzzle.

Comment: For starters: `if(player.y=250)` sets the `player.y` to `250` so it's not a "random height" but exactly what's there in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your jump function.

Instead of `if(player.y=250){` you should use `if(player.y==250){`

Also, there is a problem with the logic, you want to reduce the value of `y` to go up when the user is pressing the key, and increase the value of `y` when the user is not pressing the key to go back down like this:

```
function jump(){
    if(keys[38]){
        if(player.y>250){
            player.y-=speed*3;
        }
    } else if(player.y<380){
        player.y+=speed*5;
    }
}
```